# How do I move an element from an array to another array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, move

My code is like

```
var shapes1 = [  r.image("node.gif",190, 100, 47, 45)];
var shapes2 =[];
for (var i = 0, ii = shapes1.length; i < ii; i++) {
    shapes1[i].mousedown(function(e){
        var temp=this.clone();
        shapes1.push(temp);
        //now I want to remove "this" from shapes1
        //and put it into shape2
        //HOW??
        isDrag=true;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Maybe this is the wrong way to do it? I should be using a class instead, but isn't that for DOM items?

Comment: Maybe you should describe what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it handy to have things like

```
function removeIf(arr, predicate) {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (predicate(arr[i])) {
            arr.splice(i--, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

So then:

```
var shapes1 = [  r.image("node.gif",190, 100, 47, 45)];
var shapes2 =[];
for (var i = 0, ii = shapes1.length; i < ii; i++) {
    shapes1[i].mousedown(function(e){
        var temp=this.clone();
        shapes1.push(temp);

        removeIf(shapes1, function (item) { return item === this; });

        shapes2.push(this);

        isDrag=true;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: No problem. The nice thing about passing in a function to test each item is that you can use it to delete multiple items based on any "query" you want, e.g. instead of `item === this` it could be `item.firstName.length > item.lastName.length` to delete any item with `firstName` longer than `lastName` (okay, that's just a silly example, but you see how powerful it is).

Answer (score 1):

Use splice(index, range) to remove items from an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
const moveIndex = (arry, index, moveTo) => {
  const saved = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
    saved[i] = arry[i];

    if (moveTo > index) {
      if (i >= index) {
        arry[i] = arry[i + 1];
        //Removing chosen index
      }

      if (i >= moveTo) {
        arry[moveTo] = saved[index];
        //moving chosen index

        if (i > moveTo) {
          arry[i] = saved[i];
          //Keeping arry's order
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (i >= moveTo) {
        arry[moveTo] = saved[index];
        //moving chosen index

        if (i > moveTo) {
          arry[i] = saved[i - 1];
          //Keeping arry's order
        }
      }

      if (arry[moveTo] == arry[i]) {
        arry[i] = saved[index + 1];
        //removing duplicates
      }
    }
  }
  return arry;
};
```

Comment: There's a tiny-tiny bug in this code. The bug might appear depending on which IDE you're using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).